# Не работает паттерн Команда из книги "Лямба в Java8" Ричард Уорбертон

Tags: java

не буду описывать как я писал код сам, а потом - побуквенно с книги, и т.д. -> в конце концов я СКОПИРОВАЛ КОД из сорцов автора https://github.com/RichardWarburton/java-8-lambdas-exercises/tree/master/src/main/java/com/insightfullogic/java8/examples/chapter8
паттерн Команда. Я создал также отдельные классы, как у него в книге.
А затем написал следующий код (также как в книге) примеры 8.6,8.7, и 8.8:

[image: стр131 из книги "Лямба в Java8" Ричард Уорбертон]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО уже даже в первом коде, как и в остальных примерах,

```
    Macro macro = new Macro();
    macro.record(new Open(editor));
    macro.run();
```

конструктор класса Open не принимает editor. ни в каком виде. 
Помогите разобраться в чем проблема, ВСЕ делаю по книге, скрины книги с исходным кодом не выкладываю, т.к. они идентичны файлам на гитхабе.
 а вот так получаю NullPointerEx

```
public class Main{
public static Editor editor;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Macro macro = new Macro();
        macro.record(editor::open);
        macro.run();
    }
}
```

вот я коротко написал свое видение паттерна Комманда. и это РАБОТАЕТ.
А что навернуто\завернуто\перевернуто в примере из книги, я честно понять не могу и зачем ТАК делать, тоже не понятно.
Мой пример:

```
public class Main2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Commander commander = new Commander();
        commander.addToExec(new Run1());
        commander.addToExec(new Run2());
        commander.execAll();
    }
}

class Commander{
    List<Irun> list = new ArrayList<>();
    void addToExec(Irun irun){
        list.add(irun);
    }

    void execAll(){
        list.forEach(Irun::runner);
    }
}

interface Irun{
    void runner();
}

class Run1 implements Irun{
    @Override
    public void runner() {
        System.out.println("run1");
    }
}

class Run2 implements Irun{
    @Override
    public void runner() {
        System.out.println("run2");
    }
}
```

Comment: а у вас создан экземпляр editor? предположу, что нет. И скорее всего даже класса MockEditor  нет

Comment: так ведь editor интерфейс - разве можно создать экземпляр интерфейса? в папке command с исходниками 6 файлов. все 6 я создал, и классы и интерфейсы

Comment: @Stanislav можно создать экземпляр реализующего его класса.

Comment: что не так в шести  исходниках на гитхабе, или что должно быть в Main?

Comment: @Stanislav так там класс лежит, который реализует интерфейс. Экземпляр того класса и пихается внутрь метода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пропущен класс (https://github.com/RichardWarburton/java-8-lambdas-exercises/blob/3513bf094d215d8bd6402d502c2af62f16455c2f/src/test/java/com/insightfullogic/java8/examples/chapter8/command/MockEditor.java):

```
package com.insightfullogic.java8.examples.chapter8.command;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class MockEditor implements Editor {

    private final List<String> actions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void save() {
        actions.add("save");
    }

    @Override
    public void open() {
        actions.add("open");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        actions.add("close");
    }

    public void check() {
        assertEquals("open", actions.get(0));
        assertEquals("save", actions.get(1));
        assertEquals("close", actions.get(2));
    }

}
```

экземпляр которого и создается, и помещается внутрь метода

```
MockEditor editor = new MockEditor();

// BEGIN classBasedCommand
Macro macro = new Macro();
macro.record(new Open(editor));
macro.record(new Save(editor));
macro.record(new Close(editor));
macro.run();
// END classBasedCommand
```

Comment: спасибо, нашел. такая реализация - это правильно? нагромождение не нужных классов, т.е. так и надо делать , а не как я выложил второй пример?
выскажите пожалуйста свое мнение.